# Can i map table columns in StreamSet using any of its API?

Tags: apache, bigdata, streamsets

I need to    map 10000 column table in a Stream Set pipeline and need to send     data to it from (csv) file. So mapping each column in stream set       application by mentioning column names is very big task for 10000       columns.

So can anyone reply what is the any other simple way to achieve it?
 or can i achieve it by using its REST APIs?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this via APIs, but one approach you could look at is to create a template pipeline, export it as JSON, and add the column mappings to the JSON. There are a wide variety of tools you could use for the purpose.

Comment: But how can by template? If its by any api means , i will just call that service via HttpClient in java. But if its by in your way that you mentioned means , how can i achieve it? Any examples??  Since it has 10K Above columns, its very complecated. And i hope StreamSet will be user friendly for whatever the column size would be